# LinkedList.peek() causes nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android

I use the following Code to do get an item from a LinkedList inside an Android Activity

```
    currentAlarm = alarmQueue.peek();
```

alarmQueue itself is created like that, inside a class that extends Application

```
public static Queue<Long> getAlarmQueue() {
    if (alarmQueue == null)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "alarmqueue was null, creating new one");
        alarmQueue = new LinkedList<Long>();
    }
    return alarmQueue;
}
```

The app is in production status and released on google play, but sometimes there a error reports saying that the line containing .peek() throws an nullpointerexception. Therefore I added the null check you can see above, as I thought that alarmQueue itself was null.
Actually, after some tests, I realized that .peek() throws the nullpointerexception if the LinkedList does not contain any items.

I understand, that it may return null, but the doc doesn't say that it throws an exception
[Android Doc LinkedList](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/LinkedList.html#peek%28%29)

What am I missing here?
Thanks!

EDIT: Image proof for exception [image: Image proof for exception]
EDIT2: I found the cause.. What a terrible mistake... The type of currentAlarm was **l**ong not **L**ong, so the nullpointerexception was raised as long was the primitive data type and cannot take null as argument :/
However, this error should never happen, because at this point, there has to be something inside the queue, so I have to keep digging deeper. But for this error, everything is fine and error handling was added.

Comment: shouldnt that code be `currentAlarm = getAlarmQueue().peek();`

Comment: Note: you _are_ aware that this code is not thread safe, right? (notwithstanding the fact that you {c,sh}ould create the queue as per my answer)

Comment: Yes it is initialized, I debugged it. It really throws it on an empty linkedlist.
It could be `getAlarmQueue().peek()` you are right. This is done 3 lines before. I just forgot to write it down.

Comment: fge, that could be the problem! could you please provide some demo code?

Comment: Some demo code of what exactly? How to make it thread safe, how it can break?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, **peek() does not throw** the NullPointerException, it's the alarmQueue that is null. This can be if

1. **getAlarmQueue() has not been called before**. Think about discarding the lazy instantiation and instantiate in the constructor instead.
2. you ran into **some bad multi-threading problems**. If you are in an MT environment, consider using **volatile** (google "**double check idiom**" until you find the volatile solution, it's one of the more complicated constructs in java).

Comment: Instead of using `volatile`, just creating the queue at static init time (like in my answer) does the trick without having to resort to such black magic

Comment: @fge: In this case your version works as well, but has two drawbacks: First of all it forbids a field being non-static, which is quite a strong limitation. And second once you hit mutable fields you will have to use `volatile`. It's actually nifty white magic once you understood it.

Comment: @LastFreeNickname "it forbids a field being non-static, which is quite a strong limitation." <-- uhwhat? Look at the sample code from OP: the method is static; therefore the queue _has_ to be static! And nothing prevent you from removing `static` in that definition -- `final` instance variables are fine too, and in fact necessary if you want immutable instances. As to `volatile`, yes it has its uses, but this is not one of them imo.

Comment: @fge: That's why I wrote `**a** field` and not `**this** field`! My answer targets a more general approach as it also works with mutables. Maybe we can agree to disagree on our methods (which will both work for AndyB). :-)

Answer (score 0):

As you have created a method to get the alarmQueue so you should use it rather directly accessing the list.  Your getAlarmQueue method is making sure that the list returned is not null.

```
currentAlarm = getAlarmQueue().peek();
```

Answer (score -1):

Alternative: **don't do that**. In your class, do:

```
private static final Queue<Long> ALARM_QUEUE = new LinkedList<Long>();
```

Problem solved!

Comment: Uh, why? You just create the queue at static init time instead of having to create it in `.getAlarmQueue()`. Problem solved, definitely.

Comment: Oh, you mean the LinkedList type parameter... Fixed

Comment: I will try that. But please check the image i posted above.. It is initialized, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but your .peek() returns null here; it can happen if the queue is empty, as the javadoc says ;)